# In Star Trek, why are there so many ships named Defiant?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

**[Defiant.](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Defiant)** That's the disambiguation page. There's 4 on that page. 4.

Why does the name keep cropping up? It seems to me rather odd that there's so many of these ships, considering the wealth of names the Federation could use, and, apart from Enterprise, the rarity of seeing repeat names. (Although Valiant cropped up twice in TOS).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps it's not as odd as you expect - there have been [15 ships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Enterprise) called HMS Enterprise in the Royal Navy. 4 called Defiant does not seem so many, especially since one was a replacement and one was never mentioned on screen.

This tradition continues into Starfleet - the [list of their vessels](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Federation_starships) shows a number of repeats, for example Antares and Bradbury. And this is only the small number that we know about - there are far more ships seen on screen than are ever named, and likely many more duplicates. There is nothing special about the name Defiant.

Comment: While it is interesting to show that there are real-world parallels to the re-use of ship names (and "Enterprise" in particular has obvious resonance), it doesn't really answer the question why "Defiant" in particular.  (As opposed to, say, Excalibur.)  Can you suggest any reasons for more ships named "Defiant" than "Excalibur"?

Comment: @DavidW, there could be any number of reasons, even to as mundane as the division responsible for naming Starfleet vessels thinks the name "Defiant" is cool. There could be a large number of recycled names, they just by chance haven't appeared on screen or been referenced. We don't and can't know because there's never been a canonical list of every Starfleet ship. For all we know, the name "Borglefizz" is the most commonly used one, with a dozen vessels over 200 years proudly using that name, but since it's used for resupply ships and freighters, ships with that name don't get any screen time.

Comment: @DavidW answer updated to make the in-universe explanation more apparent

Comment: Yes I agree with @BauerPower It is not as surprising as it might seem.

Answer (score 0):

Star Trek burrow from Gene Roddenberry's naval days, thus he named all the prior ships after carriers and famous naval ships (Enterprise, Yorktown, Constitution)
While Defiant hasn't been a long term used in US Navy, the Royal Navy has had use the name HMS defiance over a dozen times. However Defiant was used only for two types of starships
One Constitution class.
and the defiant class. 
The ISS defiant built in the Mirror universe.